# git push heroku main => [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am building a React on Rails app. I tried to deploy to Heroku and am getting the following errors:

```
remote: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! While resolving: react-beautiful-dnd@13.1.0
remote: npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
remote: npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
remote: npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
remote: npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
remote: npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
remote: npm ERR!   6 more (react-dom, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom, ...)
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.5 || ^17.0.0" from react-beautiful-dnd@13.1.0
remote: npm ERR! node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd
remote: npm ERR!   react-beautiful-dnd@"^13.1.0" from the root project
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
remote: npm ERR! node_modules/react
remote: npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.5 || ^17.0.0" from react-beautiful-dnd@13.1.0
remote: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd
remote: npm ERR!     react-beautiful-dnd@"^13.1.0" from the root project
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
remote: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.r4FtS/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.r4FtS/_logs/2022-07-11T20_48_04_946Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 883925893eb2737985f5bbd30770d374d9f94ee3
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 883925893eb2737985f5bbd30770d374d9f94ee3
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to phase-5-capstone.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/phase-5-capstone.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/phase-5-capstone.git'
```

I tried running git push heroku main --force and that did not solve the issue. I see their is an issue with dependencies for react and react-beautiful-dnd but am not sure how to go about this without breaking it. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a problem with the compatibility of react-beautiful-dnd version 13.1.0 and React version 18.2.0. Downgrade to react 17 and it will work, unless you're using React Suspense, Server components or any other React 18 features.

package.json

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

If you can't downgrade, wait for the compatibility of the library react-beautiful-dnd with React 18. Take a look to github repository issues, other persons have the same problem and maybe soon it will be fixed. https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2426

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. I have downgraded to version 17.0.2 and am not using any react 18 features. Now when I run git push heroku main, I get this error:

 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '/tmp/build_655b3e9b/client/src'

Do you have any idea what this might be? I have been trying to figure it out for some time and I reinstalled react and react-dom with no resolution

Comment: I think it's because your @react-dom/client use the lastest version (compatible with react 18), just test with an older veresion compatible with React 17, like v12.1.2.